# In case of single record, don't apply where condition; In case of multiple records, apply where condition and return single record

Tags: sql, oracle

My query is regarding SQL.

I have a table with multiple records where the 'ID number' column may be duplicate. In order to remove duplication, we have put a where condition like if account number is null, do not show the record. But this is skipping the records which are only records and without account number.

We do not want the where condition to be applied if only single record exists. If multiple records exists, then only where condition should be applied.

Kindly assist.

Sample table as below:

```
ID number   Name        Account number  Country
123456      Sam                100034   China
156789      Nicky              100045   Russia
156789      Nicky                       Russia
453638      John                        Peru
564433      Bret               100035   Alaska
132323      Peter              100067   Slovenia
```

I need all unique values from above table. Hence I put a where condition to not return records where account number is null. So it returns one record for ID number 156789 but skips ID number 453638. Hence where condition should not be applied in case only one record exists for that ID number. Hope my question is clear.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the table definitions (as `create table` statements), some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question do not post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: We don't need the typing practice. Please insert sample data, expected results, table structures, etc as *text*, preferably *code* that we could copy and paste into our own tools to recreate your sample on our own machines.

Comment: DBMS is Oracle.

Comment: https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: "the 'ID number' column may be duplicate" Always cracks me up.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing more research if you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and providing a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. I suggest reading How to Ask a good question and the perfect question. Also, be sure to take the tour.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `count(*)` `over` (`partition by`...)` like this

```
select * from (
     select m.*, 
     count(*) over (partition by m.[ID number]) cnt
from MyTable as m) sel
where sel.cnt = 1 
or sel.[Account number] is not null
```

Comment: Probably you should specify the columns for the outer projection, as `select * from (` will include the business meaning-free `sel` as well.